# Specified Cast is not valid - C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do an `AppendLine` with this

```
reportLayout.AppendLine(
  "Sold Items".PadRight(25) + 
   Convert.ToString(BatchCalculation.NoOfItems(dBCommand, transDate, reportType)));
```

And I'm getting an **exception thrown**

> Specified Cast is not valid

my `NoOfItems` is a `static` method and it returns an **int**

**EDIT:** Last lines of code in `NoOfItems` method

```
            ...
            using (DbDataReader reader = dBCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            //hsBatch.currentTC = (int)reader["CURRENTTC"];
                            //hsBatch.currentAmt = (decimal)reader["CURRENTPYMTAMT"];
                            //Cancellation fee
                            hsBatch.TotalNoOfitems = (int)reader["TOTALNOOFITEMS"];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
        }

        return hsBatch.TotalNoOfitems;
    }
```

Comment: at least provide code of all mentioned indentifiers like BatchCalculation

Comment: What value is your NoOfItems method returning?

Comment: post the code for `NoOfItems` method

Comment: wait a sec.....

Comment: I'm returning an Int in NoOfitems.

Comment: Instead of `while (reader.Read()) {...}` put `if (reader.Read()) {hsBatch.TotalNoOfitems = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TOTALNOOFITEMS"]);}`

Comment: Just debug your program and see which value is being parsed actually when you get the exception. I bet it´s different from what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database can return null, so I would suggest to check [DBNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
hsBatch.TotalNoOfitems = reader["TOTALNOOFITEMS"] != DBNull.Value ? int.Parse(reader["TOTALNOOFITEMS"].ToString()):0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a problem with type mapping (*RDBMS* `Number` is not necessary *.Net* `int`):

```
   // (int) - cast like this may well be incorrect:
   // reader["TOTALNOOFITEMS"] is not nesseary int or can be cast to int
   hsBatch.TotalNoOfitems = (int)reader["TOTALNOOFITEMS"];
```

Instead of

```
  if (reader.HasRows)
  {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
          //hsBatch.currentTC = (int)reader["CURRENTTC"];
          //hsBatch.currentAmt = (decimal)reader["CURRENTPYMTAMT"];
          //Cancellation fee
          hsBatch.TotalNoOfitems = (int)reader["TOTALNOOFITEMS"];
      }
  }
```

Put

```
  // if: we don't want "while" since we read one record only
  // reader.HasRows is redundant - if we manage to read a record we have it  
  if (reader.Read()) 
  {
      // hsBatch.currentTC = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CURRENTTC"]);
      // hsBatch.currentAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["CURRENTPYMTAMT"]);

      // What ever RDBMS type mapping is (byte, short, int, long, decimal 
      // or even string - depending on query, RDBMS and settings)
      // try convert it into int - Int32 
      hsBatch.TotalNoOfitems = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TOTALNOOFITEMS"]); 
  }
```

There's one more (possible) issue: if `TOTALNOOFITEMS` field contains `NULL` value. If it's your case, you can put

```
      hsBatch.TotalNoOfitems = reader["TOTALNOOFITEMS"] == DBNull.Value
        ? 0 // or whatever value in case of null
        : Convert.ToInt32(reader["TOTALNOOFITEMS"]);
```